# Is there any Unicode equivalent for a grid of icons symbol?

Tags: html, image, grid, symbols

[image: Sample image]

Is there any such symbol that is similar in Unicode?

After all, I was able to find ☰ as a symbol, just wondering if there is anything similar to a grid of icons.

Comment: If there is none, is there any *free* icon font service like the BootStrap icons? (In fact, do the BootStrap icons have any such symbol)?

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/th/

Comment: Nevermind, the BootStrap glyph "glyphicon glyphicon-th" services the purpose quite nicely- still wondering if there is a native Unicode symbol tho.

Comment: @Sebsemillia thanks, is it free?

Comment: yes, font awesome is free to use.

Comment: Cool! @Sebsemillia might go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there is not. You can check yourself the ["Symbol, other" (So) list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm), and possibly the ["Symbol, math (Sm) list"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm) (and also [other lists](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), if you deem it worthwhile).

The closest approximation I could find is [U+25A6](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a6/index.htm), i.e., ▦ (if your browser is able to display that)

Answer (score 13):

A couple of options not already mentioned are:

- [Vertical Ellipsis](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+22EE) (⋮), repeated 3 times (⋮⋮⋮)
- [Ethiopic Tonal Mark Rikrik](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1392) (᎒), repeated 3 times (᎒᎒᎒).

Comment: this is a clever solution, it renders perfectly

Comment: neither consists of squares that have vertical and horizontal sides, unfortunately

Comment: @WalterTross, you wrote that "neither consists of squares that have vertical and horizontal sides" -- but the Ethiopic Tonal Mark Rikrik does include vertical and horizontal sides. You can see this in the enlarged version if you click the link for it in my answer.

Comment: @JoeDeRose I think you are using an inexact font. Both what you see on this page and on the linked page is rendered according to the font in use. [Here](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1200.pdf) you can see the Unicode reference, and [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1392/index.htm) is another rendering (as an image).

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly a grid of icons but character U+25A6, called "*Square with Orthogonal Crosshatch Fill*", is usually rendered as a 4x4 grid.

[image: U+25A6]

- **Unicode Group:**    Geometric Shapes
- **Hex Code:** &#x25a6;
- **Decimal Code:** &#9638;
- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25A6

There are also some Braille patterns you could use. The only problem being they only come in two columns. "*Braille Pattern Dots-12345678*" is rendered as two columns of four dots.

[image: U+28FF]

- **Unicode Group:**    Braille Patterns
- **Hex Code:** &#x28FF;
- **Decimal Code:** &#10495;
- https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+28FF

You can put one after the next and modify the kerning. In CSS it would be `letter-spacing: -.2em;` for it to be precise. It would look like this:

[image: Dot Matrix]

You can paste this in the address bar for a preview:

```
data:text/html,<html style="letter-spacing: -.2em"><meta charset="utf-8">⣿⣿
```

Comment: This display as `â£¿â£¿` for me.  Are you missing the metacharset tag?

Comment: @GirkovArpa It depends on your environment. But, you are right. I will add the meta tag to avoid problems.

Answer (score 4):

"Tetragram For Duties" 
[image]
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1d320

"Tetragram For Difficulties" 
[image]
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1d354

"Tetragram For Fostering" 
[image]
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1d356

Answer (score 3):

There is no such symbol in unicode.

You can try compose this symbol from unicode square symbols:

```
<div class="grid">
    &#x25a0;&#x25a0;&#x25a0;<br />
    &#x25a0;&#x25a0;&#x25a0;<br />
    &#x25a0;&#x25a0;&#x25a0;
</div>
```

and then adjust font params, so everything fits in the way you like it:

```
.grid {
    font-size: 7pt;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 75%;
}
```

You can see this example working at http://jsfiddle.net/8ABxV/1/

I think that better idea however, is to use "th" symbol from font-awesome framework http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/th/

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this sharp symbol

Comment: actually that character is called `'AEGEAN WEIGHT SECOND SUBUNIT' (U+10139)` (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10139/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ☰ char
2. Scale it horizontally to ~19%.
3. Stack 3 chars next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following inline hack:

`<span style="letter-spacing: -.6em">&#x22ee;&#x22ee;&#x22ee;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;`

(copy this without newlines)

It is three times the "vertical ellipsis" unicode character (⋮) with some spacing adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code using MarkDown, this works

```html
<span style="letter-spacing: -em"><meta charset="utf-8">⋮⋮⋮</span>
```

Add a leading and trailing `&nbsp;` like:

```html
Click on the 9 dot grid &nbsp;<span style="letter-spacing: -em"><meta charset="utf-8">⋮⋮⋮</span> &nbsp;that is located at the top left.
```

...And you should get:

Click on the 9 dot grid  ⋮⋮⋮  icon that is located at the top left.

[9 dot grid with surrounding text example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbRKJ.png)